# XML element with two attributes and simple element using JAXB

Tags: jaxb, jaxb2

I would like to un marshall using JAXB. I am facing issue while unmarshalling for the following use case.
Please suggest how to generate below xml using JAXB.

```
    <Source type="system" gender="male">
        <Description>He is a man</Description>
    </Source>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following.  The `@XmlAttribute` annotation is used to mark something an XML attribute.  By default everything is treated as an element, if you need the name different from the default then you can use the `@XmlElement` annotation to specify this.

```java
@XmlRootElement(name="Source")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Source {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String type;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String gender;

    @XmlElement(name="Description")
    private String description;

}
```